# Zoom functionality not working when I expand surrounding container of chart

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, lightningchart

Hi I am using lightning charts in react for plotting a line chart using the dashboard to manage 6 charts and when I increase the size the container of the dashboard the charts zoom functionality and mouse interactions are lost also the scale of the canvas is not proper after expanding the container.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a known issue and it will be addressed in LightningChart JS 2.0 release. The 2.0 release will contain "layout()" method in PublicEngine interface which can be called when  the container has been resized to trigger recalculations for the new container size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LightningChart JS version 2.0.0 and above it's possible to ask the chart to recalculate the chart layout to match the current size of the container with [`chart.engine.layout()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.0.0/interfaces/publicengine.html#layout) method. So now when you resize the container in which the chart is hosted in you can call that method and the chart will work correctly and look good again.